# Creating and deleting temp tables consecutively in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, temp-tables

This code doesn't work when I run it and I don't understand why it shouldn't, the error is that a table already exists so it doesn't seem so much as an actual bug but a bug in the verification process, perhaps I am wrong. it's something from a procedure so doesn't work to use go's everywhere.

in my first question I grossly oversimplified my problem

these were my constraints :

I use temporary tables to communicate between procedures, in this case I needed to use the same procedure twice but with different parameters so i needed the table "#a" to be informed twice. Because the way of working is to create a temporary table before executing the procedure and in that form the procedure will know if it needs to do a select or inform the table. If it informs the table it is also responsible to create column (this is done to avoid dependencies between procedures). so I can't reuse the same table because the columns have been create already.

The solution I found was to create another stored procedure which will do the work for the second part, I could have changed the procedure sp_a but I don't have actual control of it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE zzzzz_testtodelete
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #a(idtmp bit)
    Exec sp_a
        @a = 1
    .....
    DROP TABLE #a

    CREATE TABLE #a(idtmp bit)
    Exec sp_a
        @a = 2
    .....
    DROP TABLE #a
END
```

Is this normal or is it a bug from sql?

Comment: Put a `GO` in between the first `DROP` and second `CREATE`.

Comment: It has to do with how memory is managed for temp tables.  It is a compiler problem.  If you place this code into a procedure, it won't even compile claiming the same error.  It tries to allocate all of the temp tables, ignoring that at run time it would be ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal. What happens here is a compile error, not a run-time error. This is because when parsing the batch, SQL Server sees that you already have created `#a`, so creating it again will produce an error. Again, this error is not a run-time error but compile error. To test:

```
PRINT 'TESTING'

CREATE TABLE #a(idtmp bit)
DROP TABLE #a

CREATE TABLE #a(idtmp bit)
DROP TABLE #a
```

Note that `TESTING` is not printed, since the batch is not even executed due to the compile error.

Putting a `GO` in between the first `DROP` and second `CREATE` will fix the problem:

```
PRINT 'TESTING'

CREATE TABLE #a(idtmp bit)
DROP TABLE #a

GO

CREATE TABLE #a(idtmp bit)
DROP TABLE #a
```

This is because you have two separate batches now. SQL Server parses and validates sql queries by batch.

---

Only after the OP's edit that he/she states that this is used in stored procedure. In that case, there is no real solution. Still, this is a compile error. The code is not executed.

Additionally, according to [BOL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979(v=sql.100).aspx):

> If more than one temporary table is created inside a single stored
>   procedure or batch, they must have different names.

The workaround is to use different names for the tables. Or just truncate the table after the first use.

Comment: thanks, I'm not trying to find solutions as much as to understand why it fails, I figure that because I use this in a stored procedure I cannot seperate the batch and there is no "real" solution.

Comment: @MarkSinkinson, I know. But only after the OP's edit that he indicates it's an SP.

Comment: I realise that there is no real solution because the problem is that oversimplified my example. I use temporary tables as a mean of communication between stored procedures sometimes and in this very rare case I have to call the same stored procedure twice but with different parameters and because it's the stored procedure that informs the table columns I can't rename it and I need it to be deleted... so the only thing I can do is something quite ugly (empty table, add column idtemp, and delete all columns(a good 30) and it creates a dependency)... anywho, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Temp tables are less efficient in stored procedures, try using table types, you don't need to drop them.

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (idtmp bit)
```

Comment: It wasn't a Stored Procedure when i wrote the answer. It was a script.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
IF Object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null                
    Drop table #temp  
create table #temp (table columns as desired)
```