# There is already an object named '#xxx' in the database despite drop statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I have a stored procedure where there are two `INSERT INTO` statements in an `if` `else` block, one happening in `if` and the other in `else` so they don't clash. But while compiling, from the one in the else part it gives there Is already an object named '#xxx' despite it being preceded by a drop statement.

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#xxx') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #xxx

    SELECT *
    INTO #xxx
    FROM FamilyDetails_tbl FD(NOLOCK)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112865/creating-and-deleting-temp-tables-consecutively-in-a-stored-procedure/32113000#32113000) might help.

Comment: what sql version are you using>

Comment: @FelixPamittan yes that helped, but this is a part of a very big procedure, will adding Go in the middle be an issue?

Comment: @AnishaJain, no. I don't think you can use `GO` between statements in stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `select` statement into an `exec` command like this:

```
exec('SELECT *
    INTO #xxx
    FROM FamilyDetails_tbl FD(NOLOCK)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may cxecutes a command string or character string within a Transact-SQL batch.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#xxx') IS NOT NULL        
    EXEC ('SELECT 1 AS Col1 INTO #xxx')         -- IF condition
ELSE 
    EXEC ('SELECT 2 AS Col2 into #xxx')         -- ELSE condition
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try add "N" in front of tempdb like this : 
    IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#xxx') IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

It will work as ydoow has suggested above with EXEC command but if you don't have EXEC permission in that particular database then only choice is to write like below.

IF (  'Condition'  )
BEGIN
     IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#xxx') IS NOT NULL
          DROP TABLE #xxx
     SELECT
          * INTO #xxx
     FROM Table1
     WHERE 'some condition'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#xxx') IS NOT NULL
          DROP TABLE #xxx
     SELECT
          * INTO #xxx
     FROM Table1
     WHERE 'some condition'
END